# Process Builder: Ischanged() does not work for new records

Tags: process-builder, sandbox, process-automation

I am trying to create a process that runs when it meets the following criteria:

- Field A has been inserted or changed
- Field B has a certain picklist value(Attended or connected)
- Field C or Field D(Text) equals Marketing

Here is an image of my criteria(that is described above)
[image: Here is an image of my criteria(that is described above)]

And the logic used for this criteria

[image]

When I test this process, it only runs when Field A is updated. It does not run when the record is created.

How should I go about this so that it runs both when the record is created and updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the criteria into formula where you can easily access the ISNEW function which evaluates to true if record is created. You can access ISCHANGED(field) function as well.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This works. :)